# Ansible Try it out Loops - apache2, sqlite3, git install

Tags: ansible

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install list of packages
      action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
      with_items:
        - apache2
        - sqlite3
        - git
```

**Error Below:**

```
user@workspacexhnc27ngrq5uvvr3:/projects/challenge$ ansible-playbook mainplaybook.yml 
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/projects/challenge/fresco_loops/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  ^ here
user@workspacexhnc27ngrq5uvvr3:/projects/challenge$ ansible-playbook mainplaybook.yml 
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/projects/challenge/fresco_loops/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  ^ here
```

Comment: It looks like you may be working from some outdated documentation (playbooks no longer use the `action` keyword). Maybe start with the docs at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

used the apt module instead of action. Just make sure that you Ansibe user have privileged to install apt packages on your target system.

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install list of packages
      apt: 
        name: "{{item}}" 
        state: present
      with_items:
        - apache2
        - sqlite3
        - git
```